# Issue with For-Each in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Given the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
  <Interchange>
    <Group>
      <Message>
        <Loop2000>
          <Loop2300>
            <K3>
              <F449>BlaBlaBla</F449>
            </K3> 
            <K3>
              <F449>IEHPTraceID_123456</F449>
            </K3>
          </Loop2300>
        </Loop2000>
      </Message>
    </Group>
  </Interchange>
</Envelope>
```

and the following xslt:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/K3">
                    <xsl:if test="substring(/Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/K3/F449,1,11)='IEHPTraceID'">
                        <InboundDataXml>
                            <CustomAttributes>
                                 <CustomAttribute>
                                    <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
                                    <AttributeValue><xsl:value-of select="/Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/K3/F449" /></AttributeValue>
                                 </CustomAttribute>
                            </CustomAttributes>
                        </InboundDataXml>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```
<InboundDataXml>
   <CustomAttributes>
      <CustomAttribute>
         <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
         <AttributeValue>IEHPTraceID_123456</AttributeValue>
      </CustomAttribute>
   </CustomAttributes>
</InboundDataXml>
```

Obviously there is an issue with my for-each because I assume it would see the proper node and output the expected result but that is not happening. If I remove the first  node, I get the expected result. Can someone steer me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

Inside the `xsl:for-each` loop, the context is all child nodes of the *K3* element. No need to start from the root again in the XPath expressions.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/K3">
            <xsl:if test="substring(F449,1,11)='IEHPTraceID'">
                <InboundDataXml>
                    <CustomAttributes>
                        <CustomAttribute>
                            <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
                            <AttributeValue>
                                <xsl:value-of select="F449"/>
                            </AttributeValue>
                        </CustomAttribute>
                    </CustomAttributes>
                </InboundDataXml>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<InboundDataXml>
  <CustomAttributes>
    <CustomAttribute>
      <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
      <AttributeValue>IEHPTraceID_123456</AttributeValue>
    </CustomAttribute>
  </CustomAttributes>
</InboundDataXml>
```

Answer (score 1):

When use use a xsl:for-each the context is changing to the selected element. So inside the loop the context is K3 with a child-element F449. So you can test for that child directly like this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/K3">
      <xsl:if test="substring(F449,1,11)='IEHPTraceID'">
        <InboundDataXml>
          <CustomAttributes>
            <CustomAttribute>
              <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
              <AttributeValue><xsl:value-of select="F449" /></AttributeValue>
            </CustomAttribute>
          </CustomAttributes>
        </InboundDataXml>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You could get the same effect by using a predicate and without the xsl:if like this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/K3[substring(F449,1,11)='IEHPTraceID']">
      <InboundDataXml>
        <CustomAttributes>
          <CustomAttribute>
            <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
            <AttributeValue><xsl:value-of select="F449" /></AttributeValue>
          </CustomAttribute>
        </CustomAttributes>
      </InboundDataXml>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

As een alternative to xsl:foreach you could also just do this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:template match="K3"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="K3[substring(F449,1,11)='IEHPTraceID']">
    <InboundDataXml>
      <CustomAttributes>
        <CustomAttribute>
          <AttributeName>Trace Id</AttributeName>
          <AttributeValue><xsl:value-of select="F449" /></AttributeValue>
        </CustomAttribute>
      </CustomAttributes>
    </InboundDataXml>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```